# Low resolution after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, nvidia, unattended-upgrades

I was running 12.04 LTS and clicked on Upgrade to 14.04 LTS.
My screen now shows only a white window in the middle of the

screen saying:

```
The system is running in low-graphics mode
Your screen graphics card, and input device settings
could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure
these yourself.
```

The only choice is "OK"
I can get to a command prompt (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) but don't know what to do from there.

Attached is an "lspci" and an "lshw" from before I clicked on update.

```
martin@martin-desktop:~$ lspci
00:00.0 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev 

a1)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev 

a2)
00:01.1 SMBus: nVidia Corporation MCP61 SMBus (rev a2)
00:01.2 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation MCP61 Memory 

Controller (rev a2)
00:02.0 USB Controller: nVidia Corporation MCP61 USB 

Controller (rev a3)
00:02.1 USB Controller: nVidia Corporation MCP61 USB 

Controller (rev a3)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP61 PCI bridge (rev 

a1)
00:05.0 Audio device: nVidia Corporation MCP61 High 

Definition Audio (rev a2)
00:06.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation MCP61 IDE (rev a2)
00:07.0 Bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2)
00:08.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation MCP61 SATA 

Controller (rev a2)
00:08.1 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation MCP61 SATA 

Controller (rev a2)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP61 PCI Express 

bridge (rev a2)
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP61 PCI Express 

bridge (rev a2)
00:0c.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP61 PCI Express 

bridge (rev a2)
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation C61 

[GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a] (rev a2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h 

Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h 

Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h 

Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h 

Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h 

Processor Link Control
martin@martin-desktop:~$

martin@martin-desktop:~$ lshw
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
martin-desktop            
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: vsyscall64 vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory:0
          description: System memory
          physical id: 3
          size: 3710MiB
     *-cpu
          product: AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 240 Processor
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: a
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc 

msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush 

mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb 

rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good 

nonstop_tsc extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm 

cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 

3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save 

cpufreq
     *-memory:1 UNCLAIMED
          description: RAM memory
          product: MCP61 LPC Bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 0
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: a1
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
          capabilities: bus_master cap_list
          configuration: latency=0
     *-isa
          description: ISA bridge
          product: MCP61 LPC Bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: isa bus_master
          configuration: latency=0
          resources: ioport:900(size=256)
     *-serial
          description: SMBus
          product: MCP61 SMBus
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 1.1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: cap_list
          configuration: driver=nForce2_smbus latency=0
          resources: irq:11 ioport:ec00(size=64) ioport:600

(size=64) ioport:700(size=64)
     *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
          description: RAM memory
          product: MCP61 Memory Controller
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 1.2
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.2
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
          configuration: latency=0
     *-usb:0
          description: USB Controller
          product: MCP61 USB Controller
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 2
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
          version: a3
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: ohci bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=0 

maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:20 memory:fbfff000-fbffffff
     *-usb:1
          description: USB Controller
          product: MCP61 USB Controller
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 2.1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
          version: a3
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0 

maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:21 memory:fbffec00-fbffecff
     *-pci:0
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 4
          bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
          version: a1
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master 

cap_list
     *-multimedia
          description: Audio device
          product: MCP61 High Definition Audio
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 5
          bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0 

maxlatency=5 mingnt=2
          resources: irq:21 memory:fbff8000-fbffbfff
     *-ide:0
          description: IDE interface
          product: MCP61 IDE
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 6
          bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: ide bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pata_amd latency=0 

maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:0 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 

ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:ffa0(size=16)
     *-bridge
          description: Ethernet interface
          product: MCP61 Ethernet
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 7
          bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
          logical name: eth0
          version: a2
          serial: 00:25:22:81:2a:1b
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: bridge bus_master cap_list ethernet 

physical
          configuration: broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth 

driverversion=0.64 ip=192.168.1.9 latency=0 maxlatency=20 

mingnt=1 multicast=yes
          resources: irq:43 memory:fbffd000-fbffdfff 

ioport:e480(size=8)
     *-ide:1
          description: IDE interface
          product: MCP61 SATA Controller
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 8
          bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: ide bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=sata_nv latency=0 

maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:23 ioport:e400(size=8) ioport:e080

(size=4) ioport:e000(size=8) ioport:dc00(size=4) ioport:d880

(size=16) memory:fbffc000-fbffcfff
     *-ide:2
          description: IDE interface
          product: MCP61 SATA Controller
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 8.1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:08.1
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: ide bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=sata_nv latency=0 

maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:22 ioport:d800(size=8) ioport:d480

(size=4) ioport:d400(size=8) ioport:d080(size=4) ioport:d000

(size=16) memory:fbff7000-fbff7fff
     *-pci:1
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 9
          bus info: pci@0000:00:09.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pcieport
          resources: irq:40
     *-pci:2
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: b
          bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pcieport
          resources: irq:41
     *-pci:3
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: c
          bus info: pci@0000:00:0c.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pcieport
          resources: irq:42
     *-display
          description: VGA compatible controller
          product: C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a]
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: d
          bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
          version: a2
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list 

rom
          configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
          resources: irq:22 memory:fa000000-faffffff 

memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f9000000-f9ffffff 

memory:fbfc0000-fbfdffff
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor HyperTransport 

Configuration
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Address Map
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:8
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Link Control
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
  *-scsi:0
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@6
       logical name: scsi6
       capabilities: scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
  *-scsi:1
       physical id: 2
       bus info: scsi@7
       logical name: scsi7
       capabilities: scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
martin@martin-desktop:~$
```

Comment: I Read the following warning:
https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
(Not really sure why I was reading or precisely what it meant but ...)
I Hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 and typed the following command:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ubuntu


[sudo] passwordfor martin-a:
Cannot add PPA:  'ppa:xorg-edgers/ubuntu'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

I didn't expect this response so I stopped.
What shud I do?

Answer (score 0):

With a [passmark of 25](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce+7025+%2F+nForce+630a&id=1220), your system will be better off with Lubuntu or Xubuntu, but anyway, here's the solution for plain vanilla Ubuntu:

1. Read the following warning:

   https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and type the following commands:
3. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ubuntu`
4. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
5. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-349`
6. `sudo reboot`

That should fix it!